# How can I add a global bool flag to control all the doors lock states?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Now it's working fine in editor and in runtime for each door.
But I want to add a global public flag that will control all the doors at once in editor and in runtime. If I change the global flag to true all the doors will be locked and same if set to false.

The DoorsLockManager script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class DoorsLockManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector]
    public List<HoriDoorManager> Doors = new List<HoriDoorManager>();

    private void Awake()
    {
        var doors = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Door");
        Doors = new HoriDoorManager[doors.Length].ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < doors.Length; i++)
        {
            Doors[i] = doors[i].GetComponent<HoriDoorManager>();
        }
    }
}
```

And the editor script:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(DoorsLockManager))]
public class DoorsLockManagerEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty _doors;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _doors = serializedObject.FindProperty("Doors");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        for (int i = 0; i < _doors.arraySize; i++)
        {
            var door = _doors.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);

            // if door == null the script itself has an error since it can't even find the SerializedProperty
            if (door == null)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("There was an error in the editor script!\nPlease check the log", MessageType.Error);
                Debug.LogError("Couldn't get door property", target);
                return;
            }

            if (door.objectReferenceValue == null) continue;

            // FindPropertyRelative seems not to only work for MonoBehaviour classes
            // so we have to use this hack around
            var serializedDoor = new SerializedObject(door.objectReferenceValue);

            // If it's public no worry anyway
            // If it's private still works since we made it a SerializeField
            var lockState = serializedDoor.FindProperty("doorLockState");

            // Fetch current values into the serialized "copy"
            serializedDoor.Update();

            if (lockState == null)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("There was an error in the editor script!\nPlease check the log", MessageType.Error);
                Debug.LogError("Couldn't get lockState property", target);
                return;
            }

            // for the PropertyField there is 
            // no return value since it automatically uses
            // the correct drawer for the according property
            // and directly changes it's value
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(lockState, new GUIContent("Door " + i + " Lockstate"));

            // or alternatively
            //lockState.boolValue = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Door " + i + " Lockstate", lockState.boolValue);

            // Write back changes, mark as dirty if changed
            // and add a Undo history entry
            serializedDoor.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could simply add one to the `DoorsLockManager`

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class DoorsLockManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector]
    public List<HoriDoorManager> Doors = new List<HoriDoorManager>();

    // The global state
    [SerializeField] private bool _globalLockState;

    // During runtime use a property instead
    public bool GlobalLockState
    {
        get { return _globalLockState; }
        set 
        {
            _globalLocakState = value;            

            // apply it to all doors
            foreach(var door in Doors)
            {
                // now you would need it public again
                // or use the public property you had there
                Door.doorLockState = _globalLocakState;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        var doors = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Door");
        Doors = new HoriDoorManager[doors.Length].ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < doors.Length; i++)
        {
            Doors[i] = doors[i].GetComponent<HoriDoorManager>();
        }
    }
}
```

and in the editor make it "overwrite" all the other flags if changed:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(DoorsLockManager))]
public class DoorsLockManagerEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty _doors;
    private SerializedProperty _globalLockState;

    private bool shouldOverwrite;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _doors = serializedObject.FindProperty("Doors");
        _globalLockState = serializedObject.FindProperty("_globalLockState");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        serializedObject.Update();

        shouldOverwrite = false;

        // Begin a change check here
        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(_globalLockState);
        if(EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
        {
            // overwrite only once if changed
            shouldOverwrite = true;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < _doors.arraySize; i++)
        {
            var door = _doors.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);

            // if door == null the script itself has an error since it can't even find the SerializedProperty
            if (door == null)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("There was an error in the editor script!\nPlease check the log", MessageType.Error);
                Debug.LogError("Couldn't get door property", target);
                return;
            }

            if (door.objectReferenceValue == null) continue;

            var serializedDoor = new SerializedObject(door.objectReferenceValue);

            var lockState = serializedDoor.FindProperty("doorLockState");

            serializedDoor.Update();

            if (lockState == null)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("There was an error in the editor script!\nPlease check the log", MessageType.Error);
                Debug.LogError("Couldn't get lockState property", target);
                return;
            }

            // HERE OVERWRITE
            if(shouldOverwrite)
            {
                lockState.boolValue = _globalLockState.boolValue;
            }
            else
            {
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(lockState, new GUIContent("Door " + i + " Lockstate"));
            }

            serializedDoor.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

Comment: It let me only set all the doors global locked but then the global state is unchecked and can't change the doors to be unlocked.  I mean either in the editor or runtime if all the doors unlocked and I check the global state it will lock them but then the global state is unchecked so it can't be changed to unlocked anymore only one by one.

Comment: Oh yes I forgot to add the `serializedObject.Update();` and `serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();` again

Answer (score 1):

You could create a static class with the flag in it, and then have the door's "activated" state tied to it. Example:

```
public static class GlobalVariables()
{
    public static bool DoorsLocked = true; //Doors would be locked dependent on logic
}
```

Then you just set the doors' state to the global variable in code. When you change the global bool, the doors change.

```
GlobalVariables.DoorsLocked = false; //unlocks all doors reading the global bool
```

Hope this helps!